# How to push all variable values to List

Tags: c#

How to push all _aa values to _lZip ?

I have a Zip Class as below:

```
public class Zip
{
    public string Country_Code { get; set; }
    public string State_Code { get;  set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Zip_Code { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a grouped list below:

```
var _aa  = _f.GroupBy(o => new { o.properties.Country, o.properties.State, 
                o.properties.County, o.properties.City, o.properties.zipCode 
              })
                                    .Select(group => new
                                    {
                                        Country_Code = group.Key.Country,
                                        State_Code = group.Key.State,
                                        City = group.Key.City,
                                        Zip_Code = group.Key.zipCode
                                    }).ToList();
```

my question is: how to push _aa values to _lZips?

I tried:

```
_lZips = List<Zip>_aa;
```

but it gives me below error:

> Error CS0305  Using the generic type 'List' requires 1 type
>   arguments

Comment: Why not `Select(x => new Zip{....` instead of using an anonymous class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to return results in Zip type? If yes simply just create new Zip instances in the select:

```
.Select(group => new Zip
  {
    Country_Code = group.Key.Country,
    State_Code = group.Key.State,
    City = group.Key.City,
    Zip_Code = group.Key.zipCode
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: but by the way:

how about to push _xx this into _aStates as below? 

List<String> _aStates = new List<String>
 var _xx = _lCarrier_Routes.GroupBy(o => new { o.State_Code })
 .Select(group => new 
 {
      group.Key.State_Code
 }).ToList();

Comment: @Donald you will not need to create the anonymous type in the select statement in this case. Just use Select(group => group.Key.State_Code).ToList();